# Why is this message “Good Morning/Evening” on the handoff section of the app switcher?

Tags: iphone, ios, continuity

Model: iPhone 6 running on iOS 12 
This is a problem that has been bothering me for quite some time. You see, this app, bowmasters, always comes up on the app switcher in the handoff section, it’s quite annoying and I want to remove that pest. Yet when I disable handoff, IT IS STILL THERE!!! I don’t want to delete that app but at the same time don’t want to see it either. I’ve already disabled everything related to that app. Any way I can disable handoff for this????! (I don’t have any other device that have bowmasters) [image: bowmasters “good evening”]

**Update** 
Great, now stackexchange decided to annoy me.

[image: stackexchange “good morning”]

Comment: Oh your handoff list (where you see it listed) you can swipe to the left on it and then click remove or delete. It shouldn't come back after that.

Comment: Where’s the list??? Even if I disable it it is still there

Comment: Right there at the bottom where it shows Bowmasters. Just swipe it to the left and it'll reveal a delete option.

Comment: Hmm interesting, it’s not working for me, seems to just ignore the fact that I’m trying to delete it, doesn’t have any response except when I click on it, currently running iOS 12 on iPhone 6

Comment: That's pretty odd. What about 3D touching the item? Does it give any options then?

Comment: iPhone 6 don’t have 3D Touch, that stupid app that only tells you good morning, and takes up space for handoff

Comment: You should edit your post to include the model you're on.

Comment: Thanks, still figured out how to delete the handoff for this?

Comment: Is your issue with the "Good evening, Simon" message at the bottom of the image?

Comment: This seems to be now happening with every app, very strange

Comment: For me this was by WhatsApp.

Comment: @SimonCheng Just a short remark: These notifications are created by iOS, not by the apps. I sometimes see such a suggestion for an app that I developed, but I never opted in for such notifications. I guess iOS tries to be smart and suggests you an app that you frequently used during that time of the day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How to remove the annoying app "good morning/afternoon" banner in the app switching screen. 
(For Apple devices on IOS 10 + )

1. In lockscreen, swipe right.
2. Scroll all the way down to where it says "edit" and tap that.
3. You'll see the widget menu, find "Siri App Suggestions" and click the red button and remove.
4. Ta-da! Good bye annoying banners!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! new location Siri and suggestions

Turning off Siri and suggestions is now in Siri and search. Scroll down and all your apps are there , unfortunately each app has a Siri and suggestions to toggle off (which for some awful reason I think is funny).  I think it is probably  the health app (❤️Icon).
Toggled this off for tomorrow to sleep in for a couple days and see if it works.  Personally love this little easy wake up but it is definitely  a pain for days off work (like this morning).

Happy Holidays, and hopefully sleep-ins